# How can I escape @ symbol while fetching json in angular.js?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from a json using angular.
This is the json structure:

```
{
   "@rid":"#12:0",
   "@version":2,
   "@class":"Node",
   "name":"1",
   "childs":[
      {
         "@rid":"#11:2",
         "@version":1,
         "@class":"Link",
         "name":"1.4.5 --> 1.5.2.2.1",
         "parent":"#12:0",
         "from":"#12:61",
         "to":"#12:24"
      },
      {
         "@rid":"#11:3",
         "@version":0,
         "@class":"Link",
         "name":"1.5.2 --> 1.2.4",
         "parent":"#12:0",
         "from":"#12:17",
         "to":"#12:137"
      },
```

and so on..
Here I'm fetching data:

```
$http.get('nodes/nodes.json').success(function(data){
$scope.nodes = data;
});
```

And then I try to print:

```
<li class="node-children" ng-repeat="node in $parent.node.childs">
    <a ng-href="#" ng-click="">{{node.['@rid']}}</a>
</li>
```

But it doesn't work.
I also tryied {{node.["@rid"]}} but it's still not working. 
How can I escape @ symbol while fetching json?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use the dot notation to access a field, or you use the array notation. But not both. It should be

```
{{ node['@rid'] }}
```

or

```
{{ node["@rid"] }}
```